# How to pass a variable to magic ´run´ function in IPython

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-magic

I want to do something like the following:

```
In[1]: name = 'long_name_to_type_every_now_and_then.py'

In[2]: %run name
```

but this actually tries to run `'name.py'`, which is not what I want to do.

Is there a general way to turn variables into strings?

Something like the following:

```
In[3]: %run %name%
```

Comment: As the command is Equivalent to `$ python file args`, so I guess It's not possible.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

IPython expands variables with `$name`, bash-style.  This is true for *all magics*, not just `%run`.

So you would do:

```
In [1]: filename = "myscript.py"

In [2]: %run $filename
['myscript.py']
```

myscript.py contains:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

Via Python's fancy string formatting, you can even put expressions inside `{}`:

```
In [3]: args = ["arg1", "arg2"]

In [4]: %run $filename {args[0]} {args[1][-2:]}
['myscript.py', 'arg1', 'g2']
```

Comment: Just wanted to mention that this also works very nicely when just running arbitrary shell commands using an exclamation mark (!) - see the official docs - http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.10.2/html/interactive/reference.html#manual-capture-of-command-output

Comment: @minrk Just a simple question what is the difference between variable and expression. Is a dictionary variable a expression? I ask because following your example I had to use the fancy string formatting to expand the dictionary but failed when I used $ instead. I thought lists, dictionaries etc. are all variable types.

Comment: I tried that on `%%html` cell magic and it didn't work. Is there a different syntax for cell magics as opposed to line magics?

Comment: As of version 7.3, some `magics` opt out of this expansion, `time`, `timeit`, `debug` and `prun`.  https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/11516/

Comment: If you want to pass a list of arguments:  

`%run "my_script.py" {' '.join(map(str, my_arguments_list))}`

Note that you'll have to retransform the strings to whatever you need on the script's side.

Comment: this is nice for ipython. I wish it worked for a databricks notebook too

Answer (score 14):

Use `get_ipython()` to get a reference to the current [InteractiveShell](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/api/generated/IPython.core.interactiveshell.html), then call the `magic()` method:

```
In [1]: ipy = get_ipython()

In [2]: ipy.magic("run foo.py")
ERROR: File `u'foo.py'` not found.
```

**Edit** See [minrk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14411126/71522) — that's a much better way to do it.

Comment: While this isn't the best way to do it, it answered another question of mine, which was how to execute ipython magic commands within a python console (as in, while using spyder)

Answer (score 4):

In case there might be space in argument, e.g. filename, it is better to use this:

```
%run "$filename"
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is impossible with the built-in `%run` magic function. Your question led me down a rabbit hole, though, and I wanted to see how easy it would be to do something similar. At the end, it seems somewhat pointless to go to all this effort to create another magic function that just uses `execfile()`. Maybe this will be of some use to someone, somewhere.

```
# custom_magics.py
from IPython.core.magic import register_line_magic, magics_class, line_magic, Magics

@magics_class
class StatefulMagics(Magics):
    def __init__(self, shell, data):
        super(StatefulMagics, self).__init__(shell)
        self.namespace = data

    @line_magic
    def my_run(self, line):
        if line[0] != "%":
            return "Not a variable in namespace"
        else:
            filename = self.namespace[line[1:]].split('.')[0]
            filename += ".py"
            execfile(filename)
        return line

class Macro(object):
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self._value = value
        ip = get_ipython()
        magics = StatefulMagics(ip, {name: value})
        ip.register_magics(magics)

    def value(self):
        return self._value

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
```

Using this pair of classes, (and given a python script `tester.py`) it's possible to create and use a "macro" variable with the newly created "my_run" magic function like so:

```
In [1]: from custom_magics import Macro

In [2]: Macro("somename", "tester.py")
Out[2]: somename

In [3]: %my_run %somename
I'm the test file and I'm running!
Out[3]: u'%somename'
```

Yes, this is a huge and probably wasteful hack. In that vein, I wonder if there's a way to have the name bound to the Macro object be used as the macro's actual name. Will look into that.

Answer (score 1):

If by 'variable' you mean a variable available in the user namespace, then I'd suggest to use `get_ipython().ev(varname)` ([docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.interactiveshell.html)) to get your variable in your function:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import argparse
import shlex

from IPython import get_ipython
from IPython.core.magic import register_cell_magic

@register_cell_magic
def magical(line, cell):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("varname")
    # using shlex to split the line in a sys.argv-like format
    args = parser.parse_args(shlex.split(line))
    ipython = get_ipython()

    v = ipython.ev(args.varname)
    # do whatever you want here
    print(v)
```

This template above served me well - I used it to make a jinja2 cell magic that also prints to file whenever the cell is run.

Comment: Nice code... Thanks for pointing out to `get_ipython().ev(...)`, very useful!