# IPython doesn't tab-complete filenames in sub-dirs after %run

Tags: python, terminal, ipython, ipython-magic

## Intro

I can't get IPython to tab-complete filenames in sub-directories after using the %run magic function. However, completion for files in the current dir works just fine. Also, completion works perfectly if any other magic function is used.

## Cases

If I do `run ./rename-parameters.py -x ../` then hit `<TAB>`, only directories are shown:

```
In [32]: run rename-parameters.py -x ../
../01_Projektplanung/  ../04_Infos/           ../07_Test/
../02_ToDo/            ../05_Software/        ../08_Tools/
../03_Anforderungen/   ../06_Hardware/        ../09_Dokumente/
```

If I try to tab complete filenames in the current directory, e.g. `run rename-parameters.py -x R_Paramete` then hit `<TAB>`,
it completes fine.

Strangely, if I try `run rename-parameters.py -x ./R_Paramete` <\TAB> (notice the"./") it does **not** complete the filename.

If I use any other magic function regular files show up fine:

```
In [32]: %debug rename-parameters.py -x ../
../01_Projektplanung/       ../05_Software/             ../09_Dokumente/            ../diag_layerb0\ -\ Copy.c
../02_ToDo/                 ../06_Hardware/             ../Thumbs.db                ../diag_layerb0\ -\ Copy.h
../03_Anforderungen/        ../07_Test/                 ../diag_layerb0.c
../04_Infos/                ../08_Tools/                ../diag_layerb0.h
enter code here
```

Any and all ideas are appreciated.

PS: The only workaround I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14409510/797744), but it's inconvenient.