# Databricks Notebook with %run - Not working

Tags: python-3.x, azure-databricks

I have referenced the topic - [How to pass a variable to magic ´run´ function in IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409167/how-to-pass-a-variable-to-magic-%C2%B4run%C2%B4-function-in-ipython/14411126#14411126][1]) for triggering a Notebook from another Notebook.

```
notebook = "/Users/xxx/TestFolder/Notebook1"
```

In the next cell, I am trying to call %run like this as per the solution suggested in the above article:

```
%run $notebook
```

I get the below error:
Notebook not found: $notebook. Notebooks can be specified via a relative path. Is it possible to pass a string variable along with %run?

I could get around with something like this:
dbutils.notebook.run(notebook, 300 ,{})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with %run, pass param notebook_paramname

```
Python/Scala cell:
    notebook = "/Users/xxx/TestFolder/Notebook1"

Magic cell:
    %run $notebook_paramname = notebook
```

Answer (score 2):

Magic commands such as %run and %fs do not allow variables to be passed in.

The workaround is to use dbutils as you have seen.