# Problems passing variables into IPython magic functions

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, magic-function

While in a Jupyter Notebook I am trying to save the result of the IPython `%%prun` magic function to a specific file which lives in a subfolder of the current directory, say `filename = r'subfoler\profile_result.txt'`. I would like to be able to link this file name via

```
%%prun -T filename
...
```

However, when I do this, it just prints the profiler output to a file called `filename` in the current directory. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14409167/7736506) has a similar problem, for which the solution is to pass in the variable via `$filename`. This does not work, and instead just saves the output to a file called `$filename`. Is this a bug, is it not possible to do what I want, or am I incorrectly passing in the python variable?

Answer (score 0):

`%prun` docs has this note:

> ```
>     .. versionchanged:: 7.3
>        User variables are no longer expanded,
>        the magic line is always left unmodified.
> ```

I'm not sure where the expansion is normally done, but `prun` now uses

```
opts, arg_str = self.parse_options(parameter_s, 'D:l:rs:T:q',
                                       list_all=True, posix=False)
```

to handle the arguments.

`%history` on the other hand uses

```
@magic_arguments
@argument...
args = parse_argstring(self.history, parameter_s)
```

Without getting into details, that's a different parsing route.

I have version IPython 7.16.1

`%debug`, `%time` and `%timeit` have the same note.

The relevant pull-request: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/11516/

The reasoning: "Most useful for magics that take Python code on the line, e.g. %timeit, etc."