# Execute python file within for loop

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, argparse

I want to execute a python script from within a for loop.

What I tried was more or less the following:

```
input_dir_parent='/home/.../parent_folder/'
for input_directory in os.listdir(input_dir_parent):
    python process.py --input_dir  input_directory
```

So I want to pass a variable (that changes after each iteration) from the for-loop as an argument to the process.py script. This does not work however. The input_directory after --input_dir will not be a reference to the input_directory but just an 'independant' arguement (in this case it will be handled as a string 'input_directory'). Is there another way to do what I want?

Comment: Take a look at the Subprocess Module https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: `python process.py --input_dir  input_directory` is not valid Python syntax... Python is not Bash.

Comment: why not import process.py and call operation using a function. it will be more easy and useful to debug

Comment: As noted, you can call a subprocess using the `subprocess` module. Note, though, that *usually* it makes more sense to use your script *as a module*. Wrap the code that gets executed in a function that you can reuse

Comment: I assume this is tagged `argparse` because `process.py` uses that to handle commandline.  Otherwise this isn't an `argparse` problem.  It is also tagged `jupyter-notebook`.  Is that where you are running this?  `jupyter` has `magics` for running scripts, `!` and `%run`.  And the `magics` allow you to use OS like `$` and `{}` to substitute variables into the calling expression.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69153603/can-i-use-a-run-inside-of-a-for-loop

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. I think i can figure it out from here. I also realized that the approach is flawed from the beginning, so i will probably also solve it in a different way afterwards:)