# How to add token without exposing it in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am installing a package in `jupyter notebook` but I don't want my token exposed. How can I achieve this? I am using `python` and `jupyter notebook`

```
%pip install git+https://<token>@dev.azure.com/company-projects/company/_git/cpoo
```

Comment: can you set environment variable on juypter? If so, that's probably what I'd suggest using

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409167/how-to-pass-a-variable-to-magic-%C2%B4run%C2%B4-function-in-ipython This lets you use a variable in a magic command like %pip. You can load the token from whatever you'd like (user input, environment variable, file not checked into VCS etc)

Comment: @Kaia thanks, Let me try this :)

Comment: pip also support authenticate using a `.netrc` file, without need set the token in the url
(https://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/manual/html_node/The-_002enetrc-file.html)

Comment: Thanks Legends, I was able to solve this using ```import getpass```  and ```password = getpass.getpass()``` So, all good :)